# SimpleDateFormat incorrectly rolling year forward during format of Date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am currently working with a DateUtils class, that helps format dates across a system. 
I have a Date in format yyyyMMdd, which is parsed from a String.

I pass into another format to receive a "period" value, of format E d MMM YY.

The below, should give me a period of MON 31 DEC 18. However it is returning MON 31 DEC 19. Why is the year rolling forward?

Thanks

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat_E_d_MMM_YY = new SimpleDateFormat("E d MMM YY");
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat_yyyyMMdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
final Date date = dateFormat_yyyyMMdd.parse("20181231");
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(dateFormat_E_d_MMM_YY.format(date));
```

Comment: `YY` is week year use `yy`...

Comment: @Reimeus I think you can submit your comment as the answer.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo use `E d MMM yy` instead of `E d MMM YY`.

From the docs :

> y : year
>
> Y  : Week year

Answer (score 1):

You have written `YY` which means week. 
You need the year, hence you will need to write `yy`

In case you need more details you can check all the meaning of the different variables in the documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

```
y   Year            Year    1996; 96
Y   Week year       Year    2009; 09
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
w   Week in year    Number  27
W   Week in month   Number  2
D   Day in year     Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
```